# Equivalent tensorflow expression to numpy mask

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a numpy array named PixelData of unknown shape, and I am using the following condition to filter values in the array greater than some value x using a mask:

```
PixelData[PixelData>=x] = PixelData[PixelData>=x] - x
```

When I convert this numpy array to a tensor, I cannot perform the same masking operation. I have tried using tf.where as follows:

```
PixelData = tf.where(PixelData>=x, PixelData - x, PixelData)
```

In the official documentation, they always seem to define the mask dimensions in advance to equal the dimensions of the tensor being masked, but then they talk about the dimensions being broadcasted automatically, so I am a bit confused. Are these two functions equivalent? Are there any situations where they may produce different outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `PixelData` looks like, but here is working example with both methods:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = 2
np_pixel_data = np.array([[3, 4, 5, 1],
                       [6, 4, 2, 5]], dtype=np.float32)

np_pixel_data[np_pixel_data>=x] = np_pixel_data[np_pixel_data>=x] - x

tf_pixel_data = tf.constant([[3, 4, 5, 1],
                       [6, 4, 2, 5]], dtype=tf.float32)

tf_pixel_data = tf.where(tf.greater_equal(tf_pixel_data, x), tf_pixel_data - x, tf_pixel_data)

print(np_pixel_data)
print(tf_pixel_data)
```

```
[[1. 2. 3. 1.]
 [4. 2. 0. 3.]]
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 2. 3. 1.]
 [4. 2. 0. 3.]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32)
```

You might have some minor rounding differences, but nothing significant.

Comment: Excellent! So they should produce the same outputs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using tf.greater_equal instead of the >= operator? This code will likely be used in a data generator for a tf.data dataset.

Comment: No but I generally recommend using tf operations to be on the safe side.